# TypeError: listener must be a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I'm storing an event listener inside a WeakMap and upon retrieving the function to remove it from the EventEmitter this error get's thrown:

> TypeError: listener must be a function

I just can't figure out what the problem is:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var listeners = new WeakMap();
var eventEmitterA = new EventEmitter();
var eventEmitterB = new EventEmitter();

eventEmitterA.on('open', (obj) => {
  function stuff() { /* ... */ }

  listeners.set(obj, stuff);

  eventEmitterB.on('stuff', stuff);
});

eventEmitterA.on('close', (obj) => {
  var listener = listeners.get(obj);

  console.log(typeof listener); // logs "function"

  eventEmitterB.removeListener(listener);
});


var someObject = {some: 'object'};

eventEmitterA.emit('open', someObject);
eventEmitterA.emit('close', someObject);
```

Comment: What is `typeof listener` in `eventEmitterA.on('close', ...)`?  You have a `console.log()` if the typeof is function, but what is it actually there?

Comment: console.log(typeof listener) yields "function"

Comment: some [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_event_listener) might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eventEmitterB.removeListener(listener);
```

should be

```
eventEmitterB.removeListener('stuff', listener);
```

`removeListener` takes two arguments and the function is supposed to be the second argument, so you are passing the function as the name of the handler and `undefined` as the handler.